# British citizenship for someone born abroad in 1996

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

I was born on 1996 outside the UK to a British mother. Do I qualify for UK citizenship?

My grandmother was born in London, UK in 1938. My mother was registered in the UK on 12 August 1983.

Comment: Did you try using the [Official Gov.UK "Check if you're a British citizen" tool](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen)? What did it have to say?

Comment: I removed all the details regarding your grand-mother's academic career as they are not relevant.

Comment: By registered do you mean she registered as a citizen, and is a UK citizen now?

Comment: @SztupY this is probably not a duplicate as in this case the mother appears to be a citizen by descent whereas in the other the mother appears to be a citizen otherwise than by descent.

Comment: @phoog: if she registered, then she is probably otherwise than descent

Comment: @SztupY if she registered under this provision, the OP's mother is by descent: https://www.gov.uk/register-british-citizen/born-before-1983-to-british-mother.

Comment: Yes, she was registered in the UK, and she is a British citizen